# How to strip tags in a safer way than using strip_tags function?

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, strip-tags

I'm having some problems using strip_tags PHP function when the string contains 'less than' and 'greater than' signs. For example:

If I do:

```
strip_tags("<span>some text <5ml and then >10ml some text </span>");
```

I'll get:

```
some text 10ml some text
```

But, obviously I want to get:

```
some text <5ml and then >10ml some text
```

Yes I know that I could use &lt; and &gt;, but I don't have chance to convert those characters into HTML entities since data is already stored as you can see in my example.

What I'm looking for is a clever way to parse HTML in order to get rid only actual HTML tags.

Since TinyMCE was used for generate that data, I know which actual html tags could be used in any case, so a `strip_tags($string, $black_list)` implementation would be more usefull than `strip_tags($string, $allowable_tags)`.

Any thoughs?

Comment: Why is it obvious what you want to get?  `<anything` is an opening tag, and as such should be removed.  So `strip_tags` is doing what you're asking it to...

Comment: I agree with ircmaxell. Your sentence has three tags, like it or not. You will probably need a different approach. Is the source data in a consistent format? Anyway you can convert the angle brackets to their HTML encoded equivalents before stripping tags?

Comment: @ircmaxell and @clifgriffin: I wrote "obviously" because semantically those signs are not part of a tag, they are meaning 'less than five milliliters' and 'greater than 10 milliliters'.

Comment: @ircmaxell: I'm not saying that strip_tags has a bug. I'm asking for the right way to get that I need.

Comment: @clifgriffin: I don't have chance to convert those characters into HTML entities since data is already stored as you can see in my example.

Comment: @texai: my point was that it is not obvious to a computer what you're asking for.  It may feel obvious to either of us, but no programming language will free you from the burden of clarifying your own ideas.  That's what I meant from that comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a wacky workaround you could filter non-html brackets with:

```
$html = preg_replace("# <(?![/a-z]) | (?<=\s)>(?![a-z]) #exi", "htmlentities('$0')", $html);
```

Apply strip_tags() afterwards. Note how this only works for your specific example and similar cases. It's a regular expression with some heuristics, not artificial intellegince to discern html tags from unescaped angle brackets with other meaning.

Comment: since you are already using `PCRE_EXTENDED` you could add inline comments so we can better understand the Regex.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have "greater than" and "lesser than" signs, you need to escape them:

`&gt;` is >

`&lt;` is <

See e.g. this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Comment: Yes I know that, but I don't have chance to convert those characters into HTML entities since data is already stored as you can see in my example. What I'm looking for is a clever way to parse HTML in order to strip actual HTML tags

Comment: @texai: well, off you go to the land of guesswork and pain, otherwise known as Heuristics ;) @mario's answer looks kind of useful in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of strip_tags(), just use htmlspecialchars() instead.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: This doesn't meet the requirement of replacing "<span>" with "" and "</span>" with ""

Comment: htmlspecialchars() and htmlentities() will only encode the content in the string. This will not remove any tags.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the accepted answer that uses a heuristic function to try to remove tags while sparing < and > signs, here is a version that uses preg_replace_callback, as the /e modifier in preg_replace is now deprecated:

```
function HTMLToString($string){
    return htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags(preg_replace_callback("# <(?![/a-z]) | (?<=\s)>(?![a-z]) #xi",    
        function ($matches){
            return (htmlentities($matches[0]));
        }
        , $string)));
}
```