# need explanation on a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Can anyone please explain me the meaning of this regular expression?

```
$html = preg_replace("# <(?![/a-z]) | (?<=\s)>(?![a-z]) #exi", "htmlentities('$0')", $html);
```

Someone added it at [How to strip tags in a safer way than using strip_tags function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995962/how-to-strip-tags-in-a-safer-way-than-using-strip-tags-function) but i am not able to understand.

This is my first post on stackoverflow so please forgive me if i am committing anything wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: paste complete code.what is $html at the end ?

Comment: strip_tags are totally safe. But you have to use it with a loop. If someone can use the regex properly , he can make use of strip_tags properly. But the question wasnt about it of course.

Comment: Beware, the `e` modifier on `preg_replace` is a (possible) security weakness (may permit code execution) and will be deprecated in [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/preg-replace#refsect1-function.preg-replace-changelog)

Comment: @silentboy yes .. but bad i feel about strip_tags is that it strips off all the text that is between < and > does not matter if it is html tag or not

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Thanks Carlos .. i will look it further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#...#      the # and # are just characters to start en end a REGEX
           (you can use a lot of character for this)
#exi       the e, x and i flags. See the PHP.net site for information
           about it

<          the < character
(?!...)    a negative lookahead. The REGEX matches when the characters
           after this are NOT equal to one of those
[/a-z]     a character class, matches for the / character and the
           letters a - z
|          OR
(?<=\s)    a positive lookbehind. The REGEX maches when there is
           \s (whitepspace) before
>          the > character
(?![a-z])  negative lookahead for the letters a - z
```

So basically, it matches all `<` and `>` characters that are not used as a tag. For instance, `<foo` and `</foo` will not match and `foo>` will not aswell. But `1 < 3` will match. This will get passed to the `htmlentities` function and become `1 &lt; 3`. Now, you can savely use `strip_tags` to remove only the tags.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's trying to determine what's not an HTML tag based simply on whether or not the following character after < or > is a number.

This means it will capture the `<` in this:

`<span>This is <5 ml.</span>`

And replace it with the HTML entity equivalent of that character, allowing you to safely use `strip_tags` without destroying the meaning of the string (as is discussed in your referenced question).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! yes, that's true but as i am not very expert in regular expresion so i wanted to get explanation on what purpose every regular expression construct is performing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks for `<` which is not followed by `a-z`

**OR**

space followed by `>` which is not followed by `a-z`

It then replaces it with `htmlentities('$0')` where $0 is your entire match!

`i` option ignores the case

`e` does normal substitution

`x` ignores literal white space